# Создание слайдшоу delphi с картинками из БД

Tags: delphi

Беру из базы данных картинки. Все ок. Но в связи с тем что у меня в бд 3 картинки pic_ob_1 pic_ob_2 pic_ob_3 я хочу сделать слайд шоу так как такая функция уже есть у меня на сайте. Но вот как реализовывать это в delphi не понимаю.

```
j:=TJPEGImage.create();
b:=TADOBLOBStream.Create(TBlobfield(adoquery2.FieldByName('pic_ob_1')),bmRead);

if b.size=0 then
    begin
        b:=TADOBLOBStream.Create(TBlobfield(adoquery5.FieldByName('pic')),bmRead);
    end;
try
    j.loadfromstream(b);
    image1.Picture.Assign(j);`
finally
    b.Free();
    j.Free();
end;
```

Comment: Т.е. нужно извлечь из базы три картинки и их в слайд-шоу пролистать. Из базы вы умеете читать, слайд-шоу делаете. В чём тогда загвоздка?

Comment: для перехода к следующему сету картинок нужно вызвать `adoquery2.Next` и снова выполнить загрузку картинок в `image1`.